# Search For Name in Range

Tags: excel, string, vba, loops, range

Hey I was wondering if I would get some help with this sample question.

"Help bill by looking writing a sub that looks through a range of cells starting in A1 (1 column wide) containing string values. The sub should first find the entire range and assign it to a range variable "theforest" to help make searching easier. Then, look through each cell until you find the word "Edward". If it is found or not a display the result in a message. If he was found or not."

I understand the bottom portion meaning there will be an exit sub followed by an if statement. I'm just not sure how it must be structured. Thanks!

Comment: The bottom part would be wanting you to say `"He was found"` if he was found and to say `"He was not found"` if he was not found.  So you wouldn't use an `Exit Sub` in this situation.  (If you use a loop instead of a `Find`, you may use an `Exit Do` or `Exit For` to jump out of the loop.)

Comment: I'm rather confused but I drew a layout of how it should search and continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim rng, cell As Range
Dim found As Boolean: found = False
Set rng = 'you have to specify what range you want to search
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = "Edward" Then
        found = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell

If found Then
    MsgBox "Edward was found"
Else
    MsgBox "Edward was not found"
End If
```

Comment: Well, that's the homework done I guess.  `rng` will be a variant in this code rather than a Range object though.  It doesn't _find_ the entire range (I'd translate _find_ not to mean _hard coded range_) or use `theforest` so a couple of red-marks :)